# How to translate generated language in Pelican?

Tags: python, blogs, pelican

I am setting up a new Pelican blog and stumbled upon a bit of a problem. I am German, the blog is going to be in german so I want the generated text (dates, 'Page 1/5'...) to be in german. (In my post date I include the weekday)

In `pelicanconf.py` I tried
`DEFAULT_LANG = u'ger'` and
`DEFAULT_LANG = u'de'` and
`DEFAULT_LANG = u'de_DE'`
but I only get everything in `en`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try [LOCALE](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html?highlight=locale)?

```
LOCALE = ('de_DE', 'de')
```

See [Date format and locale](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html#date-format-and-locale) for more informations.

Comment: Weird. I thought I was only supposed to use LOCALE if there are multiple languages present on my site. Anyway. That fixes the date issue but not the automatically generated text in `pageination` (the 'Page 1/5' instead of 'Seite 1/5')

Comment: Ok. Looking at the source of `pagination.html` it seems that there just is no localisation specified. I'll mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a non-standard theme installed, go to the folder of that theme and navigate to the `templates` folder. There are a lot of different `html` files. If you want to translate the generated text, like "read more" or "Other articles", open the `index.html` file inside the `template` folder and search for the text you want to translate, replace it with yours and regenerate your page. Be cautious not to break the syntax of the template file, tho.